# Implementing a search function in Angular that searches through HTML content without displaying html tags

Tags: angular, innerhtml, highlight

I'm currently working on a search function in Angular designed to highlight specific words or phrases within HTML text. The challenge arises because the text to be searched includes HTML elements. When searching for elements like `class`, `<span>`, etc., the text is displayed including the HTML tags, because I'm inserting the HTML text into my application using innerHTML. The reason behind this is that I receive formatted HTML pages that need to be displayed in my application, including formatting like bold or italic text etc..

The issue is that during the search process, the HTML tags are made visible and are not ignored, while I also need to insert `<mark>` tags to highlight the searched words or text passages without destroying the HTML code's formatting.

Examples:

Search input: Bone

incoming html: `<p> bla bla <span class="italic">Bone</span>`

Expected result: `<p> bla bla <span class="italic"><mark>Bone</mark></span>`

Search input: bla

incoming html: `<p> bla bla <span class="italic">Bone</span>`

Expected result: `<p> <mark>bla</mark> <mark>bla</mark> <span class="italic">Bone</span>`

Search input: bla bone

incoming html: `<p> bla bla <span class="italic">Bone</span>`

Expected result: `<p>bla <mark>bla</mark> <span class="italic"><mark>Bone</mark></span>`

My question is: How can I implement the search function in such a way that it ignores HTML tags during the search and does not make them visible, while correctly setting the `<mark>` tags to highlight the searched word or text without affecting the HTML formatting?

Edit and solution (for me):

```js
  transform(html: string, searchText: string): any {
    if (!searchText) {
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    searchText.split(/\s+/).forEach((term) => {
      if (term) {
        this.highlightText(doc.body, term);
      }
    });
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(doc.body.innerHTML);
  }

public highlightText(node: Node, searchText: string): void {
    const escapedText = this.escapeSpecialCharactersFromText(searchText);
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      const match = node.textContent.match(escapedText);
      if (match) {
        this.replaceMatchedTextWithMarker(node, escapedText);
      }
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      this.goRecursivelyThroughTheNode(node, searchText);
    }
  }

  private goRecursivelyThroughTheNode(node: Node, searchText: string) {
    Array.from(node.childNodes).forEach((child) => this.highlightText(child, searchText));
  }

  private escapeSpecialCharactersFromText(searchText: string) {
    return new RegExp(`(${searchText.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')})`, 'gi');
  }

  private replaceMatchedTextWithMarker(node: Node, searchRegex: RegExp) {
    const highlightedHtml = node.textContent.replace(searchRegex, '<mark>$1</mark>');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = highlightedHtml;
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);
  }
```

Comment: please share the code you tried, if possible a working example on stackblitz, also mention what is wrong in the code you wrote and what needs to be fixed!

Comment: Please share what you've tried. What you're probably looking for is `nodeType`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType (walk the nodes of the text you're searching and only match on `TEXT_NODE` types).

Comment: the node was a good hint!